# Where are the session config files?

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xfce, session

In `/usr/share/xsessions` I got two .desktop files. One is `xubuntu.desktop` the othe is `xfce.desktop`. Despite the fact that some `Comment=` and `Name=` tags differ, they are identical. both run `Exec=startxfce4`. Yet, when I log in to the two different sessions they look quite different from each other. For example does the Xubuntu session have much more entries in the xfce settings window.

That brings me to the conclusion that the actual session configs must be somewhere else, but where?

I know, that I can create a custom xsession.desktop that follows the ~/.xsession but I couldn't find the files that control the sessions that are pre-installed on my system.

I run Xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about `xorg.conf` then it should be in `/etc/X11` but according to the [official page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) "*Most systems don't ship with an X config file any more, but sometimes you need one*"

From [Ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618251) it states:

```
The correct place is /etc/X11/xorg.conf, but the file doesn't exist by
default in Ubuntu (things are mostly automatically detected instead).

If you need to configure something in that file, just create it and it will be used
```

Source:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1618251